TensorFlow Can't Detect GPU (4090) with cuDNN 8.6 and CUDA 11.8 Installed
I am having trouble getting TensorFlow to detect my NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 GPU on my Windows 11 setup. Despite following various steps and troubleshooting guides, TensorFlow still doesn't recognize my GPU.
Introduce the problem
I am trying to use TensorFlow with my NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 GPU for deep learning tasks. I have installed CUDA 11.8 and cuDNN 8.6 as required. However, TensorFlow fails to detect the GPU, and all computations are performed on the CPU.
I expected TensorFlow to detect my GPU and use it for computations. Here is a summary of the steps I have taken:
Installed NVIDIA Drivers:
Ensured the latest NVIDIA drivers were installed. Verified using nvidia-smi.
Installed CUDA Toolkit 11.8:
Downloaded and installed CUDA Toolkit 11.8 from the official NVIDIA website.
Installed cuDNN 8.6:
Downloaded and installed cuDNN 8.6, ensuring the files were copied to the CUDA directory.
Installed TensorFlow:
Initially installed tensorflow-gpu but faced issues, so I switched to installing tensorflow (since GPU support is included by default in TensorFlow 2.x).
Verified Installations:
Verified that CUDA and cuDNN were correctly installed and functional using the CUDA samples provided by NVIDIA.
Set Environment Variables:
Ensured the environment variables for CUDA and cuDNN were set correctly in the system PATH.
Python Code for Verification:
python
`import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

# Simple matrix multiplication to test computation
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print("Result of matrix multiplication:\n", c)`

Output:
`No GPU found.
2024-07-31 14:23:01.757763: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI AVX512_BF16 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Result of matrix multiplication:
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 3.]
 [3. 7.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)`

Despite these efforts, TensorFlow still fails to detect the GPU. Here is a screenshot of my Task Manager showing that the GPU is active and recognized by the system:
Any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

I'm happy to report that my issue with TensorFlow not detecting my GPU has been resolved.
Issue: TensorFlow wasn't detecting my NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 GPU on my Windows setup, even though I had CUDA 11.8 and cuDNN 8.6 installed.
Solution:
Installed Python 3.8
Installed TensorFlow 2.10, the last version supporting GPU on native Windows.
Verified GPU Detection: Ran a script to verify that TensorFlow detects the GPU.
Special thanks to @comp-era for the timely and detailed assistance, which helped me resolve this issue within a few hours.
Here’s the verification output indicating the successful detection of the GPU:
TensorFlow version: 2.10.0
Num GPUs Available: 1

Thanks again for the support!

TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you need to install TensorFlow in WSL2 or use the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin.
Install CUDA and cuDNN. Ensure you have the correct versions of CUDA and cuDNN installed. Install TensorFlow 2.10 (since anything above 2.10 does not support GPU on Windows natively):
Reference for the same: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native
The text was not generated from ai but quoted from the reference website.

For the 1st time I am writing a reply on stack overflow. The whole day i have wasted and just now i got the solution by installing tensor flow 2.10.0.
Now showing Gpu is available 1
Compatibility things
Cuda 11.8 or above
Cudnn 8.0 or more
(For 11.8, cudnn 8.6)
Follow the steps to copy folders file of cudnn to cuda
Python version 3.8
